# Block windows microphone access for specific desktop apps

Tags: windows, microphone, privacy

I can turn on/off microphone access for windows apps individually. But for desktop apps, I am not being able to individually control the microphone access. The slider doesn't even show up to respective apps. There is only a global slider which can turn on/off mic access for all desktop apps.

I don't want to turn off microphone access for all apps, I want to turn it off only for some specific apps. How do I do that?
[image: Settings ->]

Comment: Typically one would just disable the access within the application itself, (Discord, Google Chrome), both have the ability to do so.

Comment: @Ramhound there's no option for that in camtasia. Even if I turn off the microphone access, it shows that it has no access but windows notifies me that camtasia is using mic in background, which messes up my headphone audio (switches to hands-free mode).
Not all apps have that level of granularity to control microphone access within itself. That's why I wanted to control mic access from windows settings.